# macOS "mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected"

Tags: linux, mac-osx, samba

I searched high and low for this answer, so I'm hoping this will be useful to someone else.

From macOS, I started receiving the error:

```
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected
```

The following is the command (and I used may variations thereof):

```
mount -t smbfs -o nosuid,-d=755,-f=644,soft smb://username:password\!@myserver.local/Share /local/path/to/Share
```

I'm connecting to a Linux server and most of the information I've read relates to macOS and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the local network changed from the typical 192.168.1.* to a 10.1.10.* network. To fix, on the server edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Under `[global]` edit the following:

```
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.1.
```

to

```
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.1. 10.1.10.
```

Or whatever fits your local network.

This is just one possible fix for this as I've read a dozen others that had no relation to my problem. :) I hope it helps.