# macOS “mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected”

Tags: linux, mac-osx, samba

To start out this is a duplicate question - however the question has no answer is at the top of the Google rankings. (I don't have enough status to answer it) [macOS "mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected"](https://serverfault.com/questions/850751/macos-mount-smbfs-server-connection-failed-socket-is-not-connected)

Scenario:
- Vmware Fusion
- Redhat 8.1
- MacOSX Mojave

I have setup a simple Samba share with a single user. I have successfully executed testparm on the linux system and can I call smbclient from the localhost of the linux machine and iterate over the shares.

All firewalls in the system have been turned off as well as as opening up the share to being 777 (this is a local dev environment)

also I have altered my config file as suggested in the following manner:
(with 2 being the beginning of my host machines IP address) server edit /etc/samba/smb.conf. Under [global] edit the following:

hosts allow = 2.

I can ping the machine, in fact I have a tomcat server that is up and running which I am actively connecting to so I know that they machines can speak to each other.

Typing in the following:

```
# mount_smbfs //someuser@1.1.1.1/somedirectory ./mntpoint
```

mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of my specific problem seems somehow to be tied to DNS ()- after searching through a number of different forums I came across the following link:
[macrumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/cant-connect-to-smb-shares.1105685/)

In the event the link goes dormant I found the following:

> I had a weird one with smb shares, before using a shortname like
>   smb://myserver worked under SL but now I have to use
>   smb://myserver.company.com and no nothing has changed in our DNS :)

I also found the following:

[apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7978716)

> my understanding is Apple had to come up with some of its own
>   implementation of SMB because they were using proprietary methods from
>   MS developers as a result SMB can run into problems with some devices.
>   I prefer CIFS for this reason.

so I did the following:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

added the following line

```
2.2.2.2 somename.com
```

saved my edits

Type the following command and press Enter:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

After that type the second command and press Enter:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

then changed my query above to the following:

```
mount_smbfs //someone@somename.com/somedirectory ./mntpoint
```

They system asked for my password and it mounted. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with my macOS (10.12) machine which has a slightly interesting setup.

- Automount SMBFS via localhost on high-numbered (8801)
- Localhost is a tunnel via a server onto the corporate network
- Then I can access my personal storage from anywhere in the world (incl. home)

however I ran into this problem today.
I tried many fixes available on the internet, including the one above, but what did solve it was this:

- Connect to the same share via Finder

and it's that simple. My gut feeling is that doing that approach flushed the stale connection that was somehow stuck. I'm sure that there is another method but restarting both automount and autofs didn't do it. I couldn't unmount the mount by hand either.